# Is it possible to use contextual bindings with StructureMap

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have an MVC4 controller like:

```
public MyThingyController 
{
  IThingy thingy1;
  IThingy thingy2;

  public MyClass(IThingy thingy1, IThingy thingy2) {
    this.thingy1 = thingy1;
    this.thingy2 = thingy2;
  }
}
```

IThingy has two different concrete implementations which I'd like to slowly move between

With ninject I'd use a [contextual binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#simple-constrained-resolution-named-bindings)

But my google foo is totally failing me in a search to find the equivalent with StructreMap

and So I want to set up StructureMap something like:

```
public class IocConfig
{
  public static IContainer GetCommonServiceLocator()
  {
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
      {
        x.For<IThingy>()
             .Use<LegacyThingy>();
        x.For<IThingy>()
             .Use<ShinyNewThingy>();
      });
    return ObjectFactory.Container;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
x.For<MyThingyController>() 
// or better interface 
// x.For<IMyThingyController>()
   .Use<MyThingyController>()
    .Ctor<IThingy>("thingy1")
     .Is<LegacyThingy>()
    .Ctor<IThingy>("thingy2")
     .Is<ShinyNewThingy>();
```